# Connections between Cesaro summation and Borel summation of series

Tags: analysis

Let  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ be a given series of numbers,

let $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n x_k$, $n=0,1,2,...$,

let $g\in \mathbb R$.

We say that this series is convergent to $g$ in the sense of Cesaro if
$$
\frac{S_0+S_1+..+S_n}{n+1}\rightarrow g
$$
as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

We say that this series is convergent to $g$ in the sense of  Borel  if
$$
e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n \frac{x^n}{n!} \rightarrow g
$$
 as  $x\rightarrow +\infty$.

What is connection between this convergence:

1. Is it true that if a series is convergent to some $g$ in the Cesaro sense then it is convergent to the same $g$ in the Borel sense?
2. Is it true that if a series is convergent simultanuously in  both  Borel and Cesaro sense, to $g$ and $h$ respectively, then $g=h$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, the answer is negative. For a counterexample It suffices to take $x_n=\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    1, & \hbox{if }n\in 2\mathbb{N} \\
    0, & \hbox{otherwise.}
  \end{array}
\right.$.

Then $S_{2n}=S_{2n+1}=n+1,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}
$

So  $$\lim_{n\infty}\dfrac{S_0+\ldots+S_n}{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Which means that $(x_n)$ converges in the   Cesaro sense to $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

In the other hand
$$e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1) \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}+e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1) \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\to+\infty\mbox{ as } x\to+\infty$$

Then  $(x_n)$ does not converge in the  Borel sense.

Comment: Why the last expressions tend  to infinity?

Comment: For $x\geq0,$$$e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\geq xe^{-x}/2\sum_{n=0}^\infty(2n)\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\geq e^{-x}/2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}=xe^{-x}\sinh(x)\to+\infty$$ as $x\to+\infty$. We show analogously that $$e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\to+\infty$$ as $x\to+\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo in the first line. But it does not affect the reasonning.